# How to set SameSite=none in drupal setcookie function

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

If there any hook or alter that which is used to add "SameSite=none" parameter in set cookies in drupal 7.

Comment: Can you provide more information here? How are you setting the cookies currently? What version of PHP are you using? What's the `Set-cookie` header that's returned to the browser. Keep in mind, setting `SameSite=None;Secure` is **only** required if you want your cookies to be sent in a cross-site / third-party context. For instructions on setting cookies in plain PHP see: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/php.md For information on the `SameSite` change, see https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

Answer (score 1):

This one is kind of tricky, since PHP 5 does not have a flag for SameSite:None; Secure; when using setcookie() or setrawcookie(). PHP 7 does, however since these functions don't escape semicolons, we can add it to the 'domain' flag and it will get set...

**Important:** this hack WILL BREAK in PHP 7.3. If you're going to use it, at least wrap it in a PHP version check like `if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70300) { ... } else { ... }`

```
setrawcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', time() + 7700, '/', 'example.com; SameSite=none;');
```

For earlier versions of PHP,  you can set the header() directly:

`header('Set-Cookie: cookie_name=cookie_value; SameSite=None;');`

As of PHP 7.3.0 the setcookie() method supports the SameSite attribute in its options and will accept None as a valid value. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

```
setcookie($name, $value, [
    'expires' => time() + 86400,
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'samesite' => 'None',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using Drupal 7 hosted on Acquia, using PHP 7.2.2; I'm really new to CMS, can you point me in which file I need to add the 'setrawcookie' function?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not using Drupal here, but ran into samesite issues and trying to set a cookie in WP while picking it up somewhere else. Tried all kinds of hints.. never got anywhere, but your answer (the PHP 7.3.0 one) fixed my issues! Upvoted!!